# Blocking myself from installing Internet Explorer 9

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

I procrastinate a lot, and my Firefox have a plugin that control the time that I spend on some sites.
But sometimes when I was blocked I just go and use Internet Explorer.

There´s a way to remove and block IE9 installation(from windows features) ?

Comment: If you can't help yourself re-installing IE then I'm going to say you've probably got bigger problems. As harsh as it may say...go outside for a bit? Sometimes, a technical answer is not the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing IE is a rather simple task, blocking it from being installed again, that is an entirely different matter all together requiring you to disable the ability to install programs entirely. You will also have to take care with Windows Updates automatically attempting to install IE on your machine again.

What you might want to do, is use an application (NetLimiter - Block applications, ports from using internet) / firewall (block applications and ports, from internet / network) / proxy (block specific url's) to determine what applications get to use the internet, what ports are allowed, what sites are allowed.

The most effective would be a proxy hosted on a separate machine, a small linux box would be suffice, configuring which url's are accesable, some proxy programs might allow you to limit duration (more accurately, only allow users internet access to specific sites between certain time frames or not at all) as well as bandwidth while being smart enough to know when data is network specific or internet specific

Answer (score 3):

Windows Update will try to install Internet Explorer 9 automatically unless you disable it. If you run `wuapp.exe` you can hide Internet Explorer 9 and it will stop trying to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Run optionalfeatures.exe, you will find a check for Internet Explorer. Remove it and click on OK.

Comment: But I always install back using optionalfeatures. There´s a way to lock me out of optionalfeatures ?

Comment: That's up to yourself I believe. You could turn administrator rights off for your account. But you can then still access it if you know the password to an administrator account. There's no way to turn that feature off completely.